# text-shadow shows on top of text of previous line, of same element

Tags: html, css, shadow

Why does text shadow render above the text that is throwing the shadow.
I would expect for all shadows to show below all of the text.

Shadow is on top the previous line:
red HATE being a shadow, should be displayed below the text of LOVE

[image: Shadow is above previous line]

Shadow is below following line:
[image]

```css
h1 {
  text-shadow: -10px -25px 0 #f00;
}
```

```html
<h1>LOVE LOVE LOVEL LOVE <br>HATE HATE HATE HATE HATE</h1>
```

Comment: Can you explain what it is you're wanting it to look like?

Comment: The fiddle you have provided is using negative shadow and the code above is using positive? what's the matter?

Comment: I would expect for shadows to always be below the text. I have so far also not found a solution to not having shadows spill over the previous line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because the text itself will be above the previous line in case of overlap thus the shadow will follow this logic:

```css
h1 {
  line-height:0.8;
}
span {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<h1>

  <span>LOVE LOVE LOVEL LOVE <br>HATE HATE HATE HATE HATE</span>
</h1>
```

As you can see the decoration of the next line hide the previous line when using background which is the same considering shadows and other properties (like border too). The decoration of each line will be above the previous one

```css
h1 {
  line-height:0.8;
  text-shadow:0px -20px #fff;
}
span {
  background:red;
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<h1>

  <span>LOVE LOVE LOVEL LOVE <br>HATE HATE HATE HATE HATE</span>
</h1>
```

---

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html) of the painting order in the step (7) *which is somehow complex* you will see that we deal with each line box in tree order (each line)

> 2. Otherwise, for **each line box** of that element:
> 3. For each box that is a child of that element, in **that line box**, in **tree order**:

Comment: I get why this is the case but it's pretty counter intuitive. You expect the shadow to be applied to the whole element at the same time, not line by line. I wonder if this is how it's defined in the spec or whether its just a result of implementation.

Comment: @JamesCoyle it's defined on the spec, check the update

Comment: I get that the render order is defined in the spec but is there anything describing how the shadow should interact with that? It seems like an oversight to me that it's rendering in this way. I can't see any situation where OPs issue would be desirable as opposed to OPs intended outcome.

Comment: @JamesCoyle you can dig more into the specification to find those details but what I know is that we consider each line box, we draw its decoration and texts then we move to the next .. it's seems intuitive for me to have such output, I would expect the text to overlap thus the shadow to do the same

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the css you wrote, the second option (here 25px) selects the position of the shadow compared the the element.
The code below,

```
h1 { text-shadow: 10px 25px 0 #f00;}
```

will create a shadow Below the H1, which is the default.
If you wish to have a shadow ABOVE the text, you need to write this :

```
h1 { text-shadow: 10px -25px 0 #f00;}
```

The difference being the minus.

Comment: My issue was that the red shadow of "HATE" is showing on top of the text"LOVE".
But since HATE is a shadow, it should be below "LOVE"